# Video not getting downloaded

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

I need to download this video **http://studiokicks.com/xtr/basic/1.mov** The video is not getting downloaded when I use the following code:

```
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:itemURL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:requestURL];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:requestURL];
NSLog(@"data - %d",[data length]);
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];


-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    if ((([httpResponse statusCode]/100) == 2)) {


        returnData = [NSMutableData data];

    }
    else
    {

        NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: NSLocalizedString(@"HTTP Error", @"Error message displayed when receving a connection error.")forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"HTTP" code:[httpResponse statusCode] userInfo:userInfo];
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    [returnData appendData:data];
    // Build an array from the dictionary for easy access to each entry
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection1
{
    NSString *filePath = [VIDEOPATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mov",videoName]];
    BOOL success = [returnData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"successfully saved - %d",success);

}
```

Comment: NSLog the returnData after this line: `returnData = [NSMutableData data];`. Is it initialized and returns a pointer?

Comment: When you traced the execution in the debugger, what did you find?

Comment: it is giving only 353 in NSLog

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to set a member `self.data` of type `NSMutableData`.
2. Before starting loading the `NSURLConnection`, initialize: `self.data = [NSMutableData new]`.
3. In the `connectionDidReceiveData` method do: [`self.data appendData:data`].
4. And in the `connectionDidFinishLoading` you can view the data.

Comment: Please see my post, I have edited. I was already doing waht you have just suggested but didnt post in the question